# how is covariate shift associated with domain adaptation?

Tags: machine-learning, transfer-learning

This question is in context to transfer learning. During my presentation on transfer learning, I was asked the difference between covariate shift and domain adaptation.

All I know is that covariate shift takes place when data distribution changes over time and that this change in data distribution changes the original domain we were working in and that since our original domain has got changed (or shifted), we need to adapt our original domain to the changed one.

So, essentially, covariate shift is the problem while domain adaptation is the remedy step taken to mitigate its effect.

Is there any other relation between the two concepts other than the one stated above. Also, could you please describe the differences between these concepts ?

Answer (score 4):

Covariate Shift: source domain and target domain have the same input space , output space . And they share the same conditional distributions of , but different marginal distributions of . Formally, $_S (y│)= _T (y│)$, but $_S (x)≠ _T (x)$.

Obviously, domain adaptation is a more general concept, it contains marginal distribution, conditional distribution and joint distribution.